# Geometric Distribution Expectation Question

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, solution-verification, geometric-distribution

Products on a production line are defective with probability $0.1$, stochastically independently of each other. Let $Y$ be the total number of products which an inspector checks
who stops when the first defective product is found.
Name the distribution which $Y$ follows. Give the corresponding weights, $E[Y]$ and $P(Y ≤ 2)$.

My answer:

Type of distribution: Y follows the geometric distribution with $Y $~$ geo(0.1)$.

Weights: For all natural numbers $k$, $P(Y=k) = (0.1)(0.9)^{k-1}$, and $0$ otherwise.

$E[Y] = \frac{1}{p} = 10 $

$P(Y \leq 2) = P(Y=1) + P(Y=2) = 0.1 + 0.09 = 0.19$

Are my answers correct ?

Comment: Yes, your solution is correct.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Okay thank you.